# Image segmentation for screenshots (Region of Interest)

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I want to compare Screenshots of different versions (same site) of a web-application. Until now I tried following approaches:

- pixel based comparison
- pixel based fuzzy comparison with Delta E
- segmented based comparison

For the latter I subdivided the screenshot in different parts of the same size and compared them via color histograms.

Now I want to subdivide the image in a more intelligent way. Maybe I could divide it in some regions of interest. Can anyone explain some approaches for that please?

Here is an example for my problem:

[image: http://cdn.browserbite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/HT-Comp.png?_ga=1.61594287.28970400.1404314972]

Comment: So, you want to segment only the text parts?

Comment: No, I don´t want to segment only the text parts. There should be segmented other elements also. But for first approach the text would be enough.

Comment: javascript might be an easier option if you are not dealing with screen shots